# Windows XP SQL Server CE issue with INDEXING on Windows Mobile Embedded 7

Tags: sql-server-ce, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6.5, activesync

This is our environment:

- Windows XP SP3 x86
- Visual Studio 2008
- Handheld: Datalogic X4 Skorpio WE7 (Don't have another WE7 device yet to see if the behavior is the same)
- `System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll`: 3.5.8080
- SQL Server CE SDF version: 3.5

**Here is what we are experiencing**:

When attempting to apply an INDEX to any table of any `.SDF` file, it executes okay and applies the constraint. This Index can be done through code or through a database viewer such as sdfviewer. The issue is only evident when the `.SDF` has been sent to the X4 skorpio. What happens is, any column that has an INDEX constraint applied to it fails to return anything but a 0 when queries (i.e. `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE [TheIndexedColumn] = 'Bananas'` returns 0, Banana's exist but if you do 'SELECT * FROM Users', you get all the columns.).

Example: table `Users`

```
UserID (INT or BIGINT or NVARCHAR) – This is the primary key and also indexed
Firstname (NVARCHAR)
LastName (NVARCHAR)
...
```

Let’s say that this `Users` table has been populated with many users with first name and last names (unique users). If we were to query the `UserID` column, we get a result of 0. If the index is removed, we are able to apply many different queries successfully.

Opening the `.SDF` file using an sdf viewer shows no sign of corruption (from what we can see). On the Datalogic X4 device, the database is able to be opened and closed without any runtime errors.

Are there any scenarios where this issue doesn’t exist?

[Please refer to this table to see where it works without fault](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTTlf.png)

**Troubleshooting findings so far:**

1. The `.SDF` (database file) behaves normally if being deployed (database opened and closed) from a Windows 7 environment
2. The issue arises only between X4 Skorpio and Windows XP (database opened and closed within an XP machine)
3. The issue is only evident when an Index is applied to any column in a table.
4. The issue is not evident on columns that do not have an index.
5. If we copy the `.SDF` file that has been kept on a Windows 7 machine to the Skorpio X4, the application behaves fine.

Any assistance would be highly appreciated as we have exhausted all options so far. Using Windows 7 is not an option :(

Comment: Is this a typo: `Select * from [TheIndexedColumn]` ?  You select from a `table` not a column

Comment: Sounds like you may have duplicate indexes, a primary key does not need an explicit index

Comment: Is the runtime version on the X4 also 8080 ?

Comment: @tcarvin - Sorry mate yes that is a typo, I have edited it

Comment: Hi @ErikEJ , Thanks for jumping in on this, so we have an X3 that runs Win CE 6.0 and an X4 device that runs WE7. 

We had some compatibility issues with installing the SqlServerCE cab files upon cold booting the devices (the X4 compains about compatibility of installing the cab file even though it seems to operate properly after install).

I have had to resort to bundling the "System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll: 3.5.8080" with the software build to both devices. No other sqlserverce supporting installations are installed. Just an FYI, deploying to Win CE6.0 has no issues at all!

Comment: Also, can confirm there are no duplicate entries, I've stripped all the data down to a very very basic sdf db file to keep things simple whilst troubleshooting. Only a few records are available in each table.

Comment: Feel free to share the add file with me..

Comment: I would also consider using a newer engine build: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/08/sql-server-compact-35-sp2-downloadable.html

Comment: Hi ErikEJ, Non of the links from your link above seem to point to a downloadable hotfix file, they all come up saying "The Hotfix is no longer available" :( Unless I going to the wrong places. Any suggestions? Much appreciated

Comment: Even Microsoft now recommends SQLite for embedded development, I hate to say it but you might want to consider converting.  Separately, I have hit that compatibility warning in the CAB, you can edit the CAB and remove that flag if you need to. (Separate topic though).

Comment: You do not write how you deploy or copy the sdf to the device. There are known issues with XP explorer doing 'format' conversions when used to copy known file types from/to device. You probably you should add the primary key to the database table from code on the device. You maly also just copy/deploy the sdf and then compare the file on the device with the original.

Comment: @nullpointer Feel free to contact me by email to get an engine update

Comment: Hi all, appreciate all the help, at the time, we changed it over to Sqlite from CE as the behaviour was too strange to determine root cause.